Why does this equation have no solution modulo $9$?
I was reading a paper and at one point they claim (and don't prove) that the following equation has no solution modulo $9$, thus it has no integer solutions (other than the trivial one):
$$-(x^2-y^2)^2+6y^4=z^2$$
However, I don't see why this is true. If you for example take $x\equiv y \equiv 3\pmod{9}$ and $z\equiv 6\pmod{9}$ this gives you a solution. What am I missing?

Perhaps they count that as a "trivial" solution, after all if you define $X=x^2,Y=y^2,Z=z^2$, then writing the equation in those variables means that your example actually created the $X=Y=Z=0\  (\text{mod} 9$ solution...

Suppose $x$, $y$ and $z$ are integers such that
$$-(x^2-y^2)^2+6y^4=z^2.\tag{1}$$
Reducing mod $3$ shows that $-(x^2-y^2)^2\equiv z^2\pmod{3}$. Because $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $3$, it follows that $z^2\equiv-(x^2-y^2)^2\equiv0\pmod{3}$, and hence also
$$z^2\equiv-(x^2-y^2)^2\equiv0\pmod{9}.$$
Then reducing $(1)$ modulo $9$ shows that $6y^4\equiv0\pmod{9}$, and so $y\equiv0\pmod{3}$. It follows that also $x\equiv0\pmod{3}$ and so $(x,y,z)=(3X,3Y,3Z)$ for some integers $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Then
$$9\left(-(X^2-Y^2)+6Y^4\right)=Z^2,$$
which shows that $Z\equiv0\pmod{3}$, say $Z=3W$. Then
$$-(X^2-Y^2)+6Y^4=W^2,$$
which shows that $(X,Y,W)=(\tfrac x3,\tfrac y3,\tfrac z9)$ is another integral solution to $(1)$. By infinite descent this shows that $x=y=z=0$.

Maybe, they meant this?
Modulo $3$ we have $-(x^2-y^2)^2$ is $0$ or $2$. And $6y^4$ is $0$. And $z^2$ is $0$ or $1$. So, $-(x^2-y^2)^2$ and $z^2$ are $0$ modulo $3$.
If $y$ is not divisible by $3$, then there is a contradiction modulo $9$: $-(x^2-y^2)^2$ and $z^2$ are divisible by $9$, and $6y^4$ is not.
So, $y$ is divisible by $3$, then $x$ is too. And $z$ too. It means we can divide every variable by $3$ and get the same equation, except $z$ will become $z/3$. Hence there is only trivial solution.
So, essentially, they just stated what modulo we should use for infinite descent here.
